# How to intercept redirection from a NSURLRequest without UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I have a method that created a NSURLRequest. If I load this NSURLRequest in a UIWebView, there are some redirections that I catch with `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`.

How can I intercept this redirections without load my request in a UIWebView ? (I do not want it at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to tell us how you're loading it to begin with. Are you using `NSURLConnection`?  Then use the `-connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` delegate method. Be sure to read the docs to understand when it will be called. It is often called just because the framework tweaked your request, before actually communicating with anything, so not every invocation is a redirect.

Comment: i want to avoid NSURLConnection from handling any redirects and want to read the response when status code is 302 i tried many things including returning nil/same request from `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse` but no avail in java apache client it works with setting "http.protocol.handle-redirects" to false
see the link of java doc thats what i want do in ios

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1169

Answer (score 1):

if i understand well you want to catch the request and not load it in the webview. If that's what you want to do, just make your method return NO.

```
           - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType.
```

Comment: No, the goal is not to use an UIWebView

Comment: So you want to interpret a url redirect without a webview? Like a redirect that is in the header of an http request?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `NSURLCache` in order to intercept any url requests.

This example: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html demonstrates using a subclass to load local files in place of remote files, but you should also be able to use a similar subclass to cancel requests or perform other actions you need.